# Next.js grpc-node usage

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, grpc, grpc-node

I use [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) but I have a problem initializing the service in [Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js) app.

**Goal:** Create client service only once in app and use it in `getServerSideProps` (**app doesn't use client-side routing**).

For example, we have a service generated with [grpc-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-tools) (only available on SSR) and then I just want to initialize it somewhere. At first I thought it can be realized in a custom `server.js`:

```
const { credentials } = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const { MyserviceClient } = require('./gen/myservice_grpc_pb');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

// Init & Export
exports.myService = new MyserviceClient(
  'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials.createInsecure(),
);

(async () => {
  await app.prepare();
  const server = express();

  server.get("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
  });
})();
```

And then use it on the homepage, for example:

```
import React from 'react';

const { GetSmthRequest } = require('../gen/myservice_pb');
const { myService } = require('../server.js');

const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <span>My HomePage</span>
  </div>
)

const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const request = new GetSmthRequest();
  request.setSomeStuff('random');

  myService.getStmh(GetSmthRequest, (err, res) => {
    //...
  })

  return {
    props: {

    }
  }
}

export default IndexPage;
```

But for some reason it's not possible to initialize the client service in the `server.js`.

---

Also I tried doing it with `next.config.js`:

```
const { credentials } = require('@grpc/grpc-js');

const { MyserviceClient } = require('./gen/myservice_grpc_pb');

module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    myService: new MyserviceClient(
      'http://localhost:3000',
      credentials.createInsecure(),
    ),
  },
};
```

This solution works, so I can use the service through `serverRuntimeConfig`, thereby initializing it only once in the entire application, but when I make a request somewhere using `getServerSideProps`, I get an error:

> Request message serialization failure: Expected argument of type ...

**Error explanation:** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845069/9464680)

> That error message indicates that message serialization
> (transformation of the message object passed to gRPC into binary data)
> failed. This generally happens because the message object doesn't
> match the expected message type or is otherwise invalid

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?
It's also interesting to see some examples of using Next.js with grpc-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a case you can use [Node.js global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

Comment: Hi Arthur, Were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: If you have any GitHub examples for NEXT + react + gRPC , it will be of great help